# Switch Statement with multiple increments - C++

Tags: c++, switch-statement

Instead of doing it like this

```
int j = 0, k = 0, l = 0, m = 0, n = 0, o = 0, p = 0, q = 0, r = 0, t = 0;

case '1':
  j++;
  break;
case '2':
  k++;
  break;
case '3':
  l++;
  break;
case '4':
  m++;
  break;
case '5':
  n++;
  break;

cout << "Numbers that end with 1" << j << endl;
cout << "Numbers that end with 2" << k << endl;
cout << "Numbers that end with 3" << j << endl;
```

What would be the more efficient way so I only use one variable yet I can output the amount of numbers that end with a certain number?

Comment: Side note: when you find yourself making sequentially-named variables of the same type you probably want an array instead. Usually the array makes the repetitive behaviours that often follow much easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an array, or a `std::map`, where the switched character is used as the index/key, and the stored value is a counter.

```cpp
int counts[5] = {};
...
char c = ...;
switch (c) {
    case '1':
    case '2':
    case '3':
    case '4':
    case '5':
        counts[c-'1']++;
        break;
}
...
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    cout << "Numbers that end with " << i+1 << ": " << counts[i] << endl;
}
```

```cpp
#include <map>

std::map<char, int> counts;
...
char c = ...;
switch (c) {
    case '1':
    case '2':
    case '3':
    case '4':
    case '5':
        counts[c]++;
        break;
}
...
for (auto &entry: counts) {
    cout << "Numbers that end with " << entry.first << ": " << entry.second << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A better way is to use an array to store your count, use remainder as the index. Here I assume the input variable is `n`.

```cpp
int count[10] = { 0 };

count[n % 10]++;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   cout << "Numbers that end with " << i << count[i] << endl;
}
```

Comment: @sewyut - Prefer this answer to the ones that suggest maps. Maps are for large, sparse data sets. Your requirement is small (only 10 entries) and probably dense. Arrays are faster and, more importantly, simpler.

Answer (score 1):

```
map<char, int> freq_table;

freq_table[ch]++;

for (map<string, int>::iterator it = freq_table.begin(); i != freq_table.end(); it++) {
    cout << (*it).first << ": " << (*it).second << eol;
}
```

or better as @Jarod42 commented:

```
for (auto [c, count] : freq_table) {
    std::cout << c << ":" << count << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Since C++11: `for (auto p : freq_table) { std::cout << p.first << ":" << p.second << std::endl;}`.

Comment: Since C++17: `for (auto [c, count] : freq_table) { std::cout << c << ":" << count << std::endl;}`.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array of int instead of creating these many variables.

```
int arr[5];
```

In each case increment the index you assigned for each case(you will have to decide which case belong to which index).
At the end print your array.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest way is to an array. See example below. In the example I also handle the edge case that the string ends in another character than 0-9. In this case I count these occurrences; other possible solutions are ignoring or generating an error.

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
  std::array<int, 11> counts{0};
  char end = '0';


  if (end < '0' || end > '9') counts[10] += 1; else 
    counts[end - '0'] += 1;

  for (int i = 0; i < 11; ++i) {
    if (i == 10) std::cout << "Other: "; else
      std::cout << std::setw(5) << i << ": ";
    std::cout << counts[i] << "\n";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

A more flexible solution is using `map`. Makes it easier to count all types of last letters, but might also make things more difficult if you are only interested in counting the characters 0-9.

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
  std::map<char, int> counts;
  char end = '0';

  counts[end] += 1;

  for (auto p = counts.begin(); p != counts.end(); ++p) {
    std::cout << p->first << ": " << p->second << "\n";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `'9'+1` is not guaranty to fit in a `char` (it is the case for ASCII and EBCDIC, but `255` would be a valid value for `'9'`).

Comment: @Jarod42 You are right; I must have been sleeping; fixed now